# D3.js data structure for split frame donut charts

Tags: javascript, dataframe, d3.js

I am trying to create a series of 10 individual donut charts. Simplified to two below:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:150};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var data = [
  {'name':'USA', 'split':[{'security':'equity','value':93.95},{'security':'fi','value':68.8}]},
  {'name':'China', 'split':[{'security':'equity','value':40},{'security':'fi','value':60}]},
];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#4f81b9","#b8cce4","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#e7eef8"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .style("display", "block");

var radius = 65;

  var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius*1.06)
  .innerRadius(radius*.8);

  var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    console.log([d.split])
    return [d.split]; });



  var arcG = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (160) + "," + (100) + ")")
  .attr("class", "arc");

  arcG.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.data.security); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Each donut is supposed to depict the ratio of two categories, as seen in the `split` array:

```
var data = [
  {'name':'USA', 'split':[{'security':'equity','value':93.95},{'security':'fi','value':68.8}]},
  {'name':'China', 'split':[{'security':'equity','value':40},{'security':'fi','value':60}]},
];
```

No errors were thrown at me, but clearly the data structure and slice mechanism is flawed -- nothing is appended.

### Question

What is a viable reconfiguration to the data structure and/or donut slice that allows me to access `split` iteratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the pie generator with the outer array, and that won't work (look at the `NaN` for the value):

```js
var data = [{
    'name': 'USA',
    'split': [{
      'security': 'equity',
      'value': 93.95
    }, {
      'security': 'fi',
      'value': 68.8
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'China',
    'split': [{
      'security': 'equity',
      'value': 40
    }, {
      'security': 'fi',
      'value': 60
    }]
  },
];


var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

console.log(pie(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of that, use the pie generator with each inner `split` array, creating an "enter" selection for the paths inside the groups:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 30,
  right: 150
};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var data = [{
    'name': 'USA',
    'split': [{
      'security': 'equity',
      'value': 93.95
    }, {
      'security': 'fi',
      'value': 68.8
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'China',
    'split': [{
      'security': 'equity',
      'value': 40
    }, {
      'security': 'fi',
      'value': 60
    }]
  },
];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#4f81b9", "#b8cce4", "#4f81b9", "#95b3d7", "#b8cce4", "#e7eef8"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', 200)
  .style("display", "block");

var radius = 65;

var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 1.06)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.8);

var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arcG = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (160) + "," + (100) + ")")
  .attr("class", "arc");

arcG.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return pie(d.split)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.data.security);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```